# Arguments error while trying to load a widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I'm configuring **sqflite** into my app so that I can be able to perform crud operations. I've been working on this for days.

Everything seems fine but when I try to load a **widget** in routes so that I can try to experiment crud operations I keep getting errors relating to arguments when calling a widget class.

This may be a simple problem but because I'm new to flutter and dart I failing to figure this out.

Below is the **main.dart** file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/pages/create_account/create_account_page.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/pages/add_person/add_person.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/models/user.dart';

void main() => runApp(SimpleApp());

final routes = {
  '/': (BuildContext context) => new CreateAccountPage(),

class SimpleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleAppState createState() => _SimpleAppState();
}

class _SimpleAppState extends State<SimpleApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Simple App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the **create_account_page.dart** file

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:com.example.money_lender_app/models/user.dart';
    class CreateAccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final User user;
      CreateAccountPage(this.user);
      @override
      CreateAccountPageState createState() => CreateAccountPageState(this.user);
    }
    //class controller
    class CreateAccountPageState extends State<CreateAccountPage> {
      User user;
      CreateAccountPageState(this.user);
      TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(); 
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //kondisi
        if (user != null) {
          nameController.text = user.name;
        }
        //rubah
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: user == null ? Text('Tambah') : Text('Rubah'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left:10.0, right:10.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget> [
                // nama
                Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, bottom:20.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nama Lengkap',             
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {                  
                      //                                                    
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                // tombol button
                Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, bottom:20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget> [
                      // tombol simpan
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                          child: Text(
                            'Save',
                            textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // current datetime
                            var currentDate = new DateTime.now();
                            if (user == null) {
                              // tambah data
                              user = User(nameController.text, currentDate, currentDate);
                            } else {
                              // ubah data
                              user.name = nameController.text;
                              user.created_at = currentDate;
                              user.updated_at = currentDate;
                            }
                            // kembali ke layar sebelumnya dengan membawa objek user
                            Navigator.pop(context, user);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(width: 5.0,),
                      // tombol batal
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                          child: Text(
                            'Cancel',
                            textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

below is the **db_helper.dart** file.

```dart
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    //mendukug pemrograman asinkron
    import 'dart:io';
    //bekerja pada file dan directory
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:com.example.simple_app/models/user.dart';
    //pubspec.yml

    class DbHelper {
      static DbHelper _dbHelper;
      static Database _database;  
      DbHelper._createObject();
      factory DbHelper() {
        if (_dbHelper == null) {
          _dbHelper = DbHelper._createObject();
        }
        return _dbHelper;
      }
      Future<Database> initDb() async {

        Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = directory.path + 'simpleapp.db';
       //create, read databases
        var todoDatabase = openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);

        return todoDatabase;
      }

      void _createDb(Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE user (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT,
            created_at DATETIME,
            updated_at DATETIME
          )
        ''');
      }
      Future<Database> get database async {
        if (_database == null) {
          _database = await initDb();
        }
        return _database;
      }
      Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> select() async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        var mapList = await db.query('user', orderBy: 'name');
        return mapList;
      }
    //create databases
      Future<int> insert(User object) async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        int count = await db.insert('user', object.toMap());
        return count;
      }
    //update databases
      Future<int> update(User object) async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        int count = await db.update('user', object.toMap(), 
                                    where: 'id=?',
                                    whereArgs: [object.id]);
        return count;
      }
    //delete databases
      Future<int> delete(int id) async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        int count = await db.delete('user', 
                                    where: 'id=?', 
                                    whereArgs: [id]);
        return count;
      }
      Future<List<User>> getUserList() async {
        var userMapList = await select();
        int count = userMapList.length;
        List<User> userList = List<User>();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
          userList.add(User.fromMap(userMapList[i]));
        }
        return userList;
      }
    }
```

Below is the **user.dart** file. It is in the model folder.

```dart
    class User {

      int _id;
      String _name;
      String _username;
      DateTime _created_at;
      DateTime _updated_at;
      // konstruktor versi 1
      User(this._name, this._created_at, this._updated_at);
      // konstruktor versi 2: konversi dari Map ke User
      User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        this._id = map['id'];
        this._name = map['name'];
        this._created_at = map['created_at'];
        this._updated_at = map['updated_at'];
      }

      // getter
      int get id => _id;
      String get name => _name;
      DateTime get created_at => _created_at;
      DateTime get updated_at => _updated_at;
      // setter  
      set name(String value) {
        _name = value;
      }
      set created_at(DateTime value) {
        _created_at = value;
      }
      set updated_at(DateTime value) {
        _updated_at = value;
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = Map<String, dynamic>();
        map['id'] = this._id;
        map['name'] = name;
        map['created_at'] = created_at;
        map['updated_at'] = updated_at;
        return map;
      }  
    }
```

The **pubspec.yaml** file has the following dependencies.

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: ^1.5.1
```

The **error log** I'm getting in the debug console is this:

```
lib/main.dart:11:55: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
  '/': (BuildContext context) => new CreateAccountPage(),
                                                      ^
lib/pages/create_account/create_account_page.dart:5:7: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      CreateAccountPage(this.user);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:16:69: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
  '/create_account': (BuildContext context) => new CreateAccountPage(),
                                                                    ^
lib/pages/create_account/create_account_page.dart:5:7: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      CreateAccountPage(this.user);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I very much need to be able to pass the right argument inside the `CreateAccountPage()`.
I'm expecting this code to work without any argument errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are missing an argument when you are calling `CreateAccountPage()`.

Its constructor is `CreateAccountPage(this.user)`, so you need either provide a User object when you're creating the account page, or remove the parameter from the constructor.

Comment: I tried adding different arguments but I keep getting similar errors. Can you help me in putting the right argument inside `CreateAccountPage()`. It will be very helpful if I'm able to pass the right argument in there.

Comment: Does it work if you pass `User("", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now())` ?

Comment: No, only one argument is needed there. And it is also rejecting any kind of string.

Comment: I copied your code and I don't get errors.
I was talking about this line in main.dart : `'/': (BuildContext context) => new CreateAccountPage(User("", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now())),`